# Сохраняет ли HSQLDB данные в БД если работает In memory внутри веб-приложения

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate, web-apps

Весь вопрос  в заголовке. Дело в том, что я использую `Hibernate + hsqldb` для своего приложения. И на данный момент столкнулся с такой неожиданностью. Каждый раз когда я запускаю приложение, **БД** всегда пустая - нету ни структуры, ни данных. Остается лишь каталог **PUBLIC**. Приходится каждый раз создавать и заполнять заново.

Вот параметры **hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test</property>
        <property name="connection.username">SA</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>-->

        <!-- Mapping files -->
        <mapping resource="User.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="Disk.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="Takenitem.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Скажите как заставить **HSQLDB** сохранять свои данные?

P.S. **hbm.ddl.auto** не предлагать ибо мне нужно чтобы данные именно хранились - проблема не в том как их создать. Просто это непорядок, что данные не сохраняются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, вы указали URL базы `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test`. Это хранилище **в оперативной памяти.**
Естественно, данные пропадают, как только процесс с базой завершает работу.

Можно указать HSQL использовать для хранения данных файлы, указав URL такого вида:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:путь_к_файлам_БД
```

<sub>— [Документация](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/deployment-chapt.html), [ответ на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4128844/2076787)</sub>

Comment: Папка resources где у меня хранятся маппинги и файл конфигурации для hibernate подойдет ?

Comment: @IngeniousTom честно? Ни малейшего представления, не работал ни с тем, ни с другим %)

Comment: Ладно - все равно спасибо